# Project Euler Exercise 30

Tags: c#

I'm trying to solve the 30th problem of [project euler](http://projecteuler.net).

[My implementation of this problem](https://github.com/stevebeauge/ProjectEuler-Csharp/blob/master/Src/ProjectEuler/P030/P30.cs) produces the good result for 4th power, but the answer for 5th power is not accepted by the site.

Can someone explains what's wrong in my code ?

Also, I'm not sure if my formula for upper bound to check is ok. If it's not, I'd appreciate to know to good solution.

Here's my code :

```
class P30
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("   " + GetMatchingNumbers(4).Sum());

        Console.WriteLine("   " + GetMatchingNumbers(5).Sum());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static IEnumerable<int> GetMatchingNumbers(int power)
    {
        for (int i = 2; i <(power + 1)*(Math.Pow(9,power)); i++)
        {
            var sumOfPowers = 0;
            var tempi = i;
            for (int x = 0; x < power; x++)
            {
                sumOfPowers += (int)Math.Pow( tempi % 10, power);
                tempi /= 10;
            }
            if (sumOfPowers == i)
            {
                yield return i;
                Console.WriteLine("With Power {0}, {1} matches", power, i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**[Edit]** I've [asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92012/what-is-the-max-possible-value-of-the-sum-of-power-of-y-of-each-digits) if my theory is exact.

Comment: Did you try to replace int with long? I suspect your calculations are overflowing the capacity of an int...

Comment: Also, are you sure about the upper bound of your loop? How did you come up with this value ?

Comment: @ThomasLevesque: there's not overflow...

Comment: my upper bound is because if power = 5, then max sum will be 9^5+9^5+9^5+9^5+9^5, which is a 6 digit number, so I simplify with (5+1)(9 pow 5). However, I don't know if its a rule, or a coincidence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is only summing the first 5 digits of the number it's checking.

Instead of

```
for (int x = 0; x < power; x++)
```

you should use a while loop instead

```
while (tempi > 0)
```

This produces the missing number you need. (hint it's 6 digits long.)

Comment: Well spotted; it happens to work with the 4th power because all matching numbers have only 4 digits...

Comment: what a shame :) I replace the loop condition by `x<= power` and it works

Comment: @ThomasLevesque: yes, I replaced with the while form. My code worked only if nbr of digit is <= power +1